# Setting a div's width to 0 results in a width of horizontal padding + border, how to get around this?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an animation to my site in which a div's width is decreased from its initial value to 0. This works great, except that a small sliver of the div remains after the animation. I discovered that the remaining width of the div is equal to the horizontal padding of the div plus the width of the border. After some further digging it appears this is the expected behavior of the div! Now, my question:

How do I set the width of a div to zero and have that ignore horizontal padding and border width? I have tried things like changing the box-sizing and messing with negative margins but have had no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: add an extra wrapper to your div that you make width:0

Comment: You can set the div style `box-sizing: border-box`. It will make the div see its width as its icontent with+padding+border all together

Comment: Setting the div to `box-sizing: border-box` did not work. Putting a wrapper around it did, but I was hoping to avoid going this route. It does answer my question though.